# iOS 7 JavaScript changes in rendering web pages?

Tags: javascript, ios, ios7

[This](https://www.deka-institutionell.de/) is a site I've been helping with some work on. As you can see, the red left/right arrows go through the main sections of the site. All works fine on the major modern browsers, and was working fine on iOS 6.

However, on iOS 7, things get very strange. The page-to-page navigation animation basically never stops. (I've checked it in Safari, Chrome and Mercury browsers on iOS 7 (on iPhone 4) and it displays the same behaviour in all of them.)

My narrower question is: How do I fix this?

My broader question is: what changes have been introduced in iOS 7 that would make this happen? Is there some change in the way that JavaScript is being rendered that would cause this to happen?

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: All browsers on iOS uses the same rendering-engine (well Safari uses a new shiny one and other ones uses an older version of it) so thats why they display the same. It sounds nasty that some behaviour has been merged back to UIWebView though, that would affect apps built with PhoneGap/Cordova as well..

Comment: Hi Karl-Johan, thanks for this. Do you have any idea if there's anything I can do about it, or what to dig in to in order to try and fix it? Thanks.

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. I haven't had time to look at iOS7 yet.